# install apk in different ROM

Tags: android, installation, apk

I develop a APK.  I  want that The apk should be only installed in Specific ROM .
 can't be installed in the third ROMs. How to do ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could match against the `ID` or `FINGERPRINT` string from the [Build class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#FINGERPRINT). I'm not sure how you'd prevent the app from being installed, but you could certainly prevent it from being started correctly.